# unable to start service in remote and local machine with sc command and net command

Tags: windows, batch, windows-command-prompt, start, net

I am trying to start the services using the below SC command and service is not coming up.

```
sc start startliq_2090
```

output:

```
SERVICE_NAME: startliq_2090  
        TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS  
        STATE              : 2  START_PENDING  
                                (NOT_STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
```

Here the status is  2  START_PENDING.

Then I tried to use the net command as below and it started the services.
net start startliq_2090
However it started with the net command.
Now I need to start the services in the remote machine, I tried with the below but it didn't worked for me.

```
net \\\"RemoteMachine" start startliq_2090
```

Even I tried with the giving the addition time using the timeout

```
timeout /t 60 /nobreak >NUL
```

but it still didn't worked for me.

Comment: You must have admin rights on the remote site, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30787763/6811411)

Comment: Yes I already hold the admin rights but still the above bat code fails to start the services.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike `SC.exe` utility, the `NET.exe` one does not accept *server* parameter:

```
^^> net start /?
The syntax of this command is:

NET START [service]


^^> sc start
DESCRIPTION:
        Starts a service running.
USAGE:
        sc <server> start [service name] <arg1> <arg2> ...

^^>
```

Use

```
SC \\RemoteMachine start startliq_2090
```

You need to have admin rights on the `\\RemoteMachine` server, of course.